# How to get data from table reference in Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have table relation like this:

[image: table relation]

Is it possible to get the data of the project from the cash mutation table?
In example in cash mutation table with id '4' I wanna call agency name from projects table.
I've done it with with (eager loading in Laravel) but it returns null like:

```
$cash_mutations = CashMutation::where('id', 4)->with('project')->get();
```

This is my CashMutation Model:

```
class CashMutation extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function balanceType(){
        return $this->belongsTo(BalanceType::class);
    }

    public function project(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'cash_mutation_id', 'id');
    }

    public function deposit(){
        return $this->hasMany(Deposit::class);
    }
}
```

and this is my Project Model:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function cashMutation(){
        return $this->belongsTo(CashMutation::class);
    }

    public function projectFunding(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProjectFunding::class);
    }

    public function SharingProfit(){
        return $this->hasMany(SharingProfit::class);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do that in Laravel? If it possible anyone want to tell me about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is definitely possible.
You don’t get an error message so the basic configuration should be fine.
I suspect that the data in the database is not correct. What’s the project_id for the CashMutation with the id 4? Is it maybe null?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you are right when you guess the cash mutation with id 4 doesn't exist . I have managed to solve it when changing `return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'cash_mutation_id', 'id');` to `return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'id', 'cash_mutation_id');` but i don't understand what's going on in that code

Comment: Ah. You have project and CashMutation each with a belongsTo relation. Try HasMany as the inverse of belongsTo. 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: @Alex1234 you are right when you guess the cash mutation with id 4 doesn't exist . But I have managed to solve it when changing return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'cash_mutation_id', 'id'); to return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'id', 'cash_mutation_id'); but I don't understand what's going on in that code